# Write special charaters with batch into file

Tags: batch-file, special-characters

How can I write these characters to file with batch?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can echo nearly all characters with batch, but not NUL.
[batch chr function](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1733)

You could use Jscript (also a batch/jscript hybrid is possible).
In Jscript there is a simple chr() function

Comment: That's a quite interesting read there :-). One side note; you write *»the NUL character seems to be impossible to handle with batch, as I suppose cmd.exe works internally with null-terminated strings. 
So you can't store a NUL in a variable.«* – You cannot store U+0000 in an environment variable at all – neither in `cmd` nor anywhere else. The environment is a block of `Var=Value\0NextVar=AnotherValue\0`. Therefore neither a variable name nor its value can contain U+0000. This is not a limitation of `cmd` but rather of how environment variables are stored in any process.

Comment: @Joey Thanks for your explanation, I forgot it as I didn't used this for 15 years. It limits the variables, but perhaps there is a way to create a NUL in a file (and output it with `TYPE myNULLfile`)

Comment: I already thought about embedding the binary gunk at the end of the batch (which can easily be skipped with a `goto :eof` or `exit /b` and then using `more +n` to output it. Doesn't quite work, sadly (it turns `\0` into `\n` for some reason). Using a separate file and shipping that is probably the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

I quick search suggests that `^` can be used to escape certain special characters. Not sure whether it will work for the characters you mentioned, but perhaps worth a try.

http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php

Comment: Yes, but there are many characters that are a bit more complicated, like CR, SUB, LF, Backspace and so on

Answer (score 0):

You cannot handle or display a nul char in the console, you 'll have to work directly with binary stream. In batch it's limited to the command type, > and >>.

What you can do is create a file with a null char inside, and write it into a file with the command >> regarding your need :

Ex :

```
:: Creating the file with the null char inside
if not exist FileWithANulCharInside.txt (fsutil file createnew FileWithANulCharInside.txt 1)
:: Adding it into a dummy file
>test.log (0<nul set /p=abc)
>>test.log type FileWithANulCharInside.txt
>>test.log (0<nul set /p=abc)
pause
```

Source : http://johnfender.fr/?p=1138